# How can i start a new activity when user clicks on the text of the checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

How can i start a new activity when user clicks on the text of the checkbox.for ex.when user clicks on terms and condition a new activity is created without changing the state of checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the entire checkbox takes a single "click" event. So, in order to have the checkbox toggle on click, and the label launch a new Activity, I would recommend that you use a horizontal LinearLayout to layout a CheckBox with no text, and a TextView with the required label. Now, you can independently handle the click on CheckBox and it's label.

Comment: ya i have done that but i wanted to see if that was also possible

Answer (score 1):

Please try below

```
 final CheckBox chk1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    chk1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "" + chk1.isChecked(), 5000)
            .show();
            if (chk1.isChecked()) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(Activity.this, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: i want to start activity when user clicks on the text of checkbox.i used the setonclicklistner but it also checks the checkbox

Comment: actually i want to go on a new screen to display terms and conditions and checkbox should not be checked

Comment: check box click then you will get it is checked or not. if checked then you will go to another activity  -- please refer answer.

Comment: thanks for ur quick answer.but it should not matter whether checkbox is checked or not anda new activity must open if text of checkbox is clicked